# Flexbox issue with wrapping and flex-grow: auto

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm struggling with a puzzle I ran myself into. I want to have tabs, which can be multiline, to fill the entire width optimally. For which flex: auto works great. However for some unrelated and unchangable circumstances I also have the container with flex-wrap: wrap and a single item covering the whole width above the tabs.

With flex: auto and flex-wrap: wrap the flex items no longer try to fit into the width by wrapping their content text — they all have it in one line and wrap if they do not fit in.

I've made a fiddle to illustrate it:
https://jsfiddle.net/d67mgqvm/

```
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexitem full">
    This is a desired behavior but it has to use a wrapper to prevent wrapping
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">  
    <div class="flexitem">
      Content can be different so I have to use flex: auto so it has more space for longer texts
    </div> 
    <div class="flexitem">
      Like I said, it can be short like this one
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="flexitem full">
    This doesn't work, even though it can fit in all the content if it wraps text inside items
  </div>  
  <div class="flexitem">
    Content can be different so I have to use flex: auto so it has more space for longer texts
  </div> 
  <div class="flexitem">
    Like I said, it can be short like this one
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been thinking on if it's even possible to do this without a wrapper for a while now. Looks like flex-basis: min-content should be something like that but it only works in FF...

Comment: I am confused, what are you trying to achieve? Everything in one line or something else? the code in your fiddle don't match the code you pasted, which is the code you have?

Comment: I have created a fiddle with 2 sections. The top code works like I want it to, but it has an additional wrapper. The lower section in the fiddle is what I want to try and change to behave like the top on, but without having the wrapper tag.

Comment: Remove `flex: auto` for your flexitems, doesn't that solve the issue?

Comment: No, without flex: auto they all take up equal space, I specifically wrote that because text is different I need it to distribute widths optimally across all flex items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like flex-basis: min-content is what I am looking for, unfortunately it is not yet implemented anywhere other than Firefox.